# Using `ISerializable.GetObjectData` not setting `$type` despite `TypeNameHandling.Auto`

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Using JSON.NET v5.0.5, I have opted to use `ISerializable` over `DataMember` or `JsonProperty` attributes. I prefer using `ISerializable` as it allows me to have complete control over serialization without being dependent on JsonProperty etc on my classes.

I have declared the following JsonSerializer...

```
new JsonSerializer
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };
```

Where `TypeNameHandling.Auto` *should* include `$type` when the object being serialized is not the same as the declaring type.

---

When using `DataContract` I do get the expected JSON:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class MyParent
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "c")]
        public SomeBase Child { get; private set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class MyChild : SomeBase
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "p")]
        public String MyProperty { get; private set; }
    }
```

Resulting in the expected JSON of:

`{"c":{"$type":"...+MyChild,...","p":"My Test String"}}`

---

However, if I modify `MyParent` to the following:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class MyParent : ISerializable
    {
        public SomeBase Child { get; private set; }

        void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("c", Child);
        }
    }
```

The resulting JSON is:

`{"c":{"p":"My Test String"}}`

---

I would have thought that since `Child` is declared as `SomeBase` and passed off to the serializer as `Object`, that `TypeNameHandling.Auto` would have included the `$type` when given `Child` was set to an instance of `MyChild`.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

---

*UPDATE*
Opened work item on CodePlex [TypeNameHandling.Auto and ISerializable](https://json.codeplex.com/workitem/24354)

Comment: What happens if you set `TypeNameHandling` to `All`?

Comment: @Brian, if I turn on `All` then `$type` will be written, however I would prefer to avoid the extra data when the type can be inferred.

Comment: Well, at least you have a workaround then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my update above, this is an issue with the current implementation within JSON.NET (Json.NET 5.0 Release 5) and will hopefully be addressed in a future release.

In the mean time I have set-up a custom JsonConverter class for each type that required extended serialization to allow my classes to remain free of `DataContract` and `JsonProperty` attributes.

CodePlex Issue: https://json.codeplex.com/workitem/24354